# Get condition set in the admin widget in the product loop?

Tags: product-attribute, condition, conditions-serialized

Is it possible to get the condition value set in the admin widget and display it in the product loop template? For example, in my theme
**/lumachildtheme/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml**

```
<div class="block-content">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
        <div class="products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
            <ol class="product-items <?= /* @noEscape */ $type ?>">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
```

Inside the loop, I am looking to add the condition category for each iteration. I am trying to build a custom Owl Carousel with filtering options, and would like to add the condition values as a data parameter.

I am using luma sample data, so for example, in the screenshot below I want to get the value responsible for each iteration in the loop. So if it is a product in "Jackets" return the value "Jackets" or in "Hoodies & Sweatshirts" and so on. Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Comment: I tried using **<?php var_dump($_item->getData()); ?>** but no condition values. When I use **<?php echo $block->getData('conditions_encoded'); ?>** that has the condition category IDS but I don't think I can use that.

Comment: Also I see how I am able to get *Number of Products to Display* from the widget admin configuration using **getData()** but no matter what I try as a parameter, I can't get the conditions value.